How can i switch between 2 react components on the same page?
I'm trying to create a Login and Sign Up page in React Js, the idea is that that they should be rendered on the same page, and user should be able to switch between them (something like this example:https://codepen.io/guycode/pen/VwaKVrb)
i create a toggle function and the switching between the two mode work but the problem is when i switch to signup mode the url still "/Login" and the other big problem that the style and the front end design of the page stop work as it should Although when the tow mode signup and login are separate without the toggle mode the style work great
import UserServices from '../Services/service';
import img1 from '../pages/students.png';
import img2 from '../pages/students2.png';
import React, { useState } from "react";
import toast, {Toaster} from 'react-hot-toast';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faCircleExclamation} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const Signup = () => {

    const [firstName , setfirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName , setlastName] = useState('')
    const [birthday , setbirthday] = useState('')
    const [password , setpassword] = useState('')
    const [email , setemail] = useState('')
    const [errors , setErrors] = useState(
        {
            firstName : '',
            lastName : '',
            email : '',
            password : '',
            birthday : '',

    });


    const formValidation = () =>{
        const pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z0-9@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;

        let localErrors = {...errors}
        if(firstName === ""){
            localErrors.firstName = 'First name required';
        }
        if(lastName === ""){
            localErrors.lastName = 'Last name required';
        }
        if(email === ""){
            localErrors.email = 'Email required';
        }
        if ((password === "") || (!pattern.test(password))){
            localErrors.password = 'Password required';
        } 
        if(birthday === ""){
            localErrors.birthday = 'date required';
        }

        setErrors(localErrors);
        console.log(localErrors);

        const isValid = Object.values(localErrors).every(error => error === '');
        return isValid;

    }

    const signUp = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        if (formValidation()){
            const data = {
                firstName : firstName,
                lastName : lastName,
                email : email,
                password : password,
                birthday : birthday,
            }

            try {
                const response = await UserServices.signup(data)
                console.log("response ====>", response);
                toast.success('Successfully created!');
                setfirstName('');
                setlastName('');
                setemail('');
                setpassword('');
                setbirthday('');
                
                
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
                toast.success('Successfully created!');
    
            }

        }else{
            console.log("form invalid");
        }
    }


    return (
        <div class="container">
        <div class="forms-container">
        <Toaster />
            <div class="signin-signup">
                <form action="#" class="sign-up-form" onSubmit={signUp}>
                    <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value={firstName} onChange={ (e)=>setfirstName(e.target.value)}/>
                        {errors.firstName !== '' && (
                          <div className="error-message">
                             <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
                              {errors.firstName}
                               </div>
                                  )}

                        
    

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value={lastName} onChange={ (e)=>setlastName(e.target.value)}/>
                        {errors.lastName !== '' && (
        <div className="error-message">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
            {errors.lastName}
        </div>
    )}
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={ (e)=>setemail(e.target.value)} />
                        {errors.email !== '' && (
        <div className="error-message">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
            {errors.email}
        </div>
    )}
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={ (e)=>setpassword(e.target.value)} />
                        {errors.password !== '' && (
        <div className="error-message">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
            {errors.password}
        </div>
    )}
      </div>             
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="date" placeholder="Date_of_Birth" value={birthday} onChange={ (e)=>setbirthday(e.target.value)}/>
                        {errors.birthday !== '' && (
        <div className="error-message">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
            {errors.birthday}
        </div>
    )}
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="panels-container">
            <div class="panel left-panel">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>New in our faClub ?</h3>
                    <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us.</p>
                    <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">Sign up</button>
                </div>
                <img src={img1} class="image" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="panel right-panel">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>One of our faClub ?</h3>
                    <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info.</p>
                    <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">Sign in</button>
                </div>
                <img src={img2} class="image" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    


    )

}
export default Signup


import UserServices from '../Services/service';
import img1 from '../pages/students.png';
import img2 from '../pages/students2.png';
import React, { useState } from "react";
import toast, {Toaster} from 'react-hot-toast';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faCircleExclamation} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';




const SignIn = () => {
    const [password , setpassword] = useState('')
    const [email , setemail] = useState('')
    const [errors , setErrors] = useState(
        {
            email : '',
            password : '',

    });

    const formValidation = () =>{
        const pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z0-9@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;

        let localErrors = {...errors}
        if(email === ""){
            localErrors.email = 'Email required';
        }
        if ((password === "") || (!pattern.test(password))){
            localErrors.password = 'Password required';
        } 

        setErrors(localErrors);

        const isValid = Object.values(localErrors).every(error => error === '');
        return isValid;

    }

    const signin = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("forme submitted");

        if (formValidation()){
            const data = {
                email : email,
                password : password,
            }

            try {
                const response = await UserServices.signin(data)
                console.log("response ====>", response);
                toast.success('Successfully Loget in!');
                setemail('');
                setpassword('');
                
                
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
                toast.success('Successfully created!');
    
            }

        }else{
            console.log("forme invalid")

        }
    }
    

    return (
        <div class="container">
<div class="forms-container">
<Toaster />
    <div class="signin-signup">
        <form action="#" class="sign-in-form" onSubmit={signin}>
            <h2 class="title">Sign in</h2>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={ (e)=>setemail(e.target.value)}/>
                {errors.email !== '' && (
                  <div className="error-message">
                     <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
                      {errors.email}
                       </div>
                          )}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={ (e)=>setpassword(e.target.value)} />
                {errors.password !== '' && (
<div className="error-message">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircleExclamation} />
    {errors.password}
</div>
                )}
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panels-container">
    <div class="panel left-panel">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>New in our faClub ?</h3>
            <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us.</p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-up-btn">Sign up</button>
        </div>
        <img src={img1} class="image" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel right-panel">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>One of our faClub ?</h3>
            <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info.</p>
            <button class="btn transparent" id="sign-in-btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>
        <img src={img2} class="image" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>



)

}

export default SignIn;


import './App.css';
import Signup from './pages/signup.js';
import SignIn from './pages/login.js';
import img1 from '../src/pages/students.png';
import img2 from '../src/pages/students2.png';

import { useState } from 'react';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [isSignUpMode, setIsSignUpMode] = useState(false);

  const toggleMode = () => {
    setIsSignUpMode(prevMode => !prevMode);
  };
  return (
<div className={`container ${isSignUpMode ? 'sign-up-mode' : ''}`}>
    <div className="forms-container">
      {isSignUpMode ? <Signup /> : <SignIn />}
    </div>
    <div className="panels-container">
      <div className="panel left-panel">
        <div className="content">
          <h3>New in our faClub ?</h3>
          <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us.</p>
          <button className="btn transparent" onClick={toggleMode}>Sign up</button>
        </div>
        <img src={img1} className="image" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="panel right-panel">
        <div className="content">
          <h3>One of our faClub ?</h3>
          <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info.</p>
          <button className="btn transparent" onClick={toggleMode}>Sign in</button>
        </div>
        <img src={img2} className="image" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )}




export default App;



import express from 'express';
import { signup } from '../controllers/user.controller.js';
import { signin } from '../controllers/user.controller.js'; 
    const router = express.Router();
    router.post('/signup' ,signup );
    router.post('/login',signin);


export {router};


the there is no problem in the App.css

That is a common case of using Outlet in react, Outlet is used in parent route element and then 2 child route elements can be rendered inside the route of parent route, firstly You will setup your router in this way
I think you can do something like this to define your routes in a way such that /login and /signup goes through an auth outlet that way you can switch between the two and the route would change


// * index.jsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import Login from "./login";
import SignUp from "./signup";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "auth",
        element: <App />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "login",
                element: <Login />,
            },
            {
                path: "signup",
                element: <SignUp />,
            },
        ],
    },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>,
);


// * App.jsx

import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      This is app route and this is app
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}



// * login.jsx

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
      <p>
        Already have an account? <Link to="/auth/signup">Sign Up</Link>
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;



// * signup.jsx

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const SignUp = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Sign Up Page</h1>
      <button><Link to="/auth/login">Go to Login</Link></button>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



Handling it in this way you can keep the styles of both signup and login separate which might solve the issue plus it would even solve /login part.
And you will have two different routes /login and /signup for your app, hi
